# Lubuntu 14.04.1 Login Screen Resolution is Not Perfect

Tags: lubuntu, resolution, intel-graphics, login-screen

I have recently done a fresh installation(not DUAL Boot) of Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS i386 on my desktop. Now the problem is, my screen resolution is 1366x768, i.e. I am using a wide screen monitor and when the system starts and after booting the login screen appears, it is showing a bad resolution. It looks like the screen is compressed from right to left side and almost 1/3rd of the screen portion from the right side is black and remaining 2/3rd is the login screen. But if I logged is successfully the resolution of the desktop is showing perfect, i.e. 1366x768. Can anyone help me with this problem? Why the login screen resolution is not showing perfectly while the desktop resolution is perfect? My Machine Configuration is: 2GB DDR2 RAM, 80GB SATA HDD, Gigabyte Motherboard, Intel G45 Graphics Chipset, Realtek HD Audio, AOC 15.6 Inch Wide Screen Monitor....

I have already updated all the softwares and also installed the latest Intel Graphics Driver from this website - https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads. I have downloaded the "Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Ubuntu* 14.04, 32-bit" and installed the file perfectly. Still the same!!